# Why can't I instantiate this class?

Tags: php

Trying to build a simple oop solution but can't understand why I can't instantiate this class. I'm using an interface, class and implementing the class on an index.php but I'm getting a not found class error. What am I doing wrong?

Interface:

```
namespace interfaces;

interface ISales
{
}
```

Class:

```
namespace classes;

use interfaces\iSales;

class Sales implements iSales
{
}
```

Implementation (index.php):

```
use classes\Sales;

$sales = new Sales();
```

Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'classes\Sales' not found in ...

Error: Class 'classes\Sales' not found in
```

Comment: Do you either include/require the file with your Sales class or use an autoloader?

Comment: You need to use composer and the autoloader function in order to use namespaces in PHP

Comment: Have you required the class file in your index.php? e.g. ````require_once('class.php')````

Comment: @Borjante you do not _need_ composer, but you do need an autoloader.

Comment: @neil yeah sorry, but Id recommend composer everyday :)

Comment: Please read about PSR1, PSR2 and PSR4. Also start using composers bundled autoloader: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments. I've just used composer for that using this example: https://enterprise-level-php.com/2017/12/25/the-magic-behind-autoloading-php-files-using-composer.html

I'm coming from C# so PHP works a little bit different.